Guessing game error. Wrote the logic perfectly, But it's not working
The code just keep saying to insert larger number or smaller number. but don't get it to the actual number and break, though the logic is fine in my opinion. Sometimes the console doesn't print anything and it keeps roaming like infinite loop. Can anyone help me to understand what's going on!??
//  Modify the guessing game you created to allow the user to guess within a dynamic range (e.g., "Guess a number between 50 and 150"). Ensure the user cannot enter a guess outside of this range.
while (true) {
  let randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 50;
  let userGuess = prompt("Guess the Number: (50-150)");
  userGuess = parseInt(userGuess);
  if (!isNaN(userGuess) && userGuess >= 50 && userGuess <= 150) {
    if (userGuess == randNumber) {
      console.log("congrats! right guess");
      break;
    } else if (userGuess < randNumber) {
      console.log("Try large Number");
    } else if (userGuess > randNumber) {
      console.log("Try small number");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Wrong input. Try a valid Number between (50-150)");
  }
}


Are you sure the logic is 'perfect'? You're generating a new random number on every iteration. You also need to add a small timeout before showing the next prompt in order to give the UI/console time to update.

you are right. I should put the randNumber outside the loop. but still showing error. can you please help??

I've added an answer below which address some other issues in the logic.

"still showing error": I cannot reproduce that. What is the error and on which line?

Thanks. It's working now after generate the randNumber outside the loop and restart the browser.

The main issue in your code is because you're generating a new random number in every iteration of the loop. To fix this, move the line of code that generates the number outside of your while loop.
That being said, running this logic in a while loop is not a good approach. A better idea would be to define a function which contains the logic to request the user input and handle their choice and call this recursively until they get the right number.
Also note that you'll need to add a slight delay before showing the next prompt() so that the UI/console has time to update.
Here's a working example with the above changes made:


const getUserGuess = (target) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let userGuess = prompt("Guess the Number: (50-150)");
    userGuess = parseInt(userGuess, 10);
    
    if (isNaN(userGuess) || userGuess < 50 || userGuess > 150) {
      console.log("Invalid input. Try a valid Number between (50-150)");
      getUserGuess(target);
      return;
    }

    if (userGuess == target) {
      console.log("Congrats! Correct guess");
    } else if (userGuess < target) {
      console.log("Try a larger number");
      getUserGuess(target);
    } else if (userGuess > target) {
      console.log("Try a smaller number");
      getUserGuess(target);
    }
  }, 50);
}

getUserGuess(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 50);




No problem, glad to help

On every iteration of the loop, you generate a new random number, which is probably not what you meant.
Put the random number generation before the loop to give the end user multiple opportunities at guessing it:
let randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101)+50;
while (true) {
    // etc...

